# check a given string has any span tags or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `angularjs`. Now, I am facing some issues which is like -

I have a string,

```
Driven professional with broad technical skill-set, very strong attention to detail and over 8 years experience in front-end web development.
```

In this I have highlighted the string `8 years` with adding the span class to this text. Now I have handled the select text and right click event. Now, When user selects this text and the right click on it, then I get the selected text, there I want to check whether the selected string has any span or not ? How can I check this ? Thanks in advance.

```
$scope.doSomethingWithSelectedText = function (event) {
          var valueofSelection = handleClick(event);
          var selectedText = getSelectedText();
        };


var handleClick = function (evt) {
          if (evt.button === 2) {
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        };
```

Whole text is in one `p` and in that adding some spans

Comment: Did you try using regular expressions?

Comment: Yes I did but no luck because I get a string in the same manner, I tried using the event object .

Comment: You’ll need to show us more of your code for us to understand how far you’ve got.

Comment: You want to check if a `<p>some html</p>` has a <span> in the content?

Comment: I mean , When I select  some text then if the part of that text is present in the span text or not

Answer (score 0):

You can put the whole string into a DOM Element, then use `getElementsByTagName` to get all spans from it.

```
const getAllSpanTags = (text) => {
  let $p = document.createElement('p')
  $p.innerHTML = text;
  return $p.getElementsByTagName('span') || [];
}

let spans = getAllSpanTags(YOUR_TEXT_HERE);
console.log(spans);
```